# Custom key bindings in OSX terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, key-bindings

Is there any way to make truly custom key bindings in OSX terminal? I know that Preferencer->Profiles->Keyboard offer some, though tedious, customisations. However, I would like to make my terminal key bindings similar to my emacs bindings. I expected to find something by simply googling but I find surprisingly little. All help is truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

gotta use the Automator, and this tutorial is the best on the net:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/58986/automator-for-mac-tutorial-and-examples

Edit: basically you will create a script (service) in automator and then you have to hook it to a keyboard shortcut: System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts. Select Services from the sidebar and find your service.